NuxtJS move generate files from dist folder automatically
I have a small NuxtJS website for own usage that is hosted on my own NAS.
Atm I use the "yarn generate" command to create all the files and move all the files from the dist folder to my NAS by hand. That is annoying and I want to automate that.
My first try was to automatically generate the files to my NAS by changing the nuxt.config.js and adding a dir for generating. The problem is that the building progress completly deletes/empties the destination dir to fill it again. But I have some more stuff inside the root folder of my webserver on my NAS, like phpadmin. So I can not do that.
Anyone has a different idea?
I googled if I can turn of the deletion of the dist folder, but it looks like I can`t.
Can I somehow attach a new script to the generate command, that moves the files to my NAS?

You could pipe the command into a mv something like this
yarn generate && mv -f dist ../coold-directory/.

More details here.
Using some basic Bash Linux command is safe and flexible enough IMO.
